Reflexive verb and pronoun
I've been having a bit of difficulty grasping the use of particular reflexive and non-reflexive verbs, especially when they conjugate the same as each other. I understand the non-reflexive use, so my questions are thus:
Am I correct in saying that when I say:
Me siento cansado hoy.

... that the reflexive pronoun "me" is mandatory because I'm using the reflexive verb (sentirse) because I'm stating how I'm feeling? Is it also correct if I said:
Yo me siento cansado hoy.

... ie. the "Yo" is superfluous and unnecessary (because the conjugation of the verb signifies the subject), but the "me" is still required, like above, as the verb is reflexive so it requires the reflexive pronoun?

Both of them are correct, nevertheless, when speaking is more common to say "Me siento cansado hoy" omitting the subject

I'd say that the subject tends to always be omitted, both in written and spoken language. It will only be included mostly for emphasis, for example after hearing sb else say that they feel well: En cambio, YO me siento cansado hoy.

For a beginner I think the Spanish custom of omitting the subject pronoun is quite hard to get used to. In general you would always omit it unless it gives rise to ambiguity which usually only arises with the third person form of the verb. As Gustavson remarks in a comment you would use it for emphasis. The fact that you have the reflexive pronoun (me) there does not alter the principle.
